# I have to post data into server using asynctask post method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have tried to post data into server using Asynctask,but it show only one data it is not accepting multiple data to a file.these are my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private EditText value,value1;
private Button btn;
String string;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    value1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //string=value.getText().toString();
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new
```

MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString(),value1.getText().toString());
    }

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        postData(params[0],params[1]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void postData( String valueIWantToSend,String abc) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.104/AndroidUploadImage/receiver.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("one word",abc));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: you wanted to post file and String parametrs

Comment: it's not accepting any string.so i am making gettext().tostring() in argument list itself.